# Angular : how to use external library that creates and manages the DOM

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dom

I'm creating an angular >2 library that wraps another library written in vanilla/plain javascript.

This external library is a gallery .It manipulates the DOM (create/remove/update elements) and manages events (click).

My problem when using this library inside an angular component is that the generated DOM is not viewed by angular and the attribute _ngcontent-xxx is missing in generated html... and styles are not applied.

How should this kind of external libraries be managed in an angular context ?

Comment: can you provide a link to the library?

Comment: What I would like is to understand the general behavior. But there is the library  : https://github.com/Ecodev/natural-gallery-js

The elements are created by document.createElement(...) and then added by xxx.appendChild(yyy)

Answer (score 0):

Just include the library in your .angular-cli.json file like this:

```
//....
styles": [
                "scss/style.scss",
                "../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/kasper/theme.css",
                "../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
                "../node_modules/dragula/dist/dragula.css",
                "../node_modules/ng2-toastr/bundles/ng2-toastr.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
                "../node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.min.js",
                "../node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js"
            ],
//
```

Comment: Yes, they can be added globally but it's not a best practice when creating an angular that exposes a component. The css should be included in the component declaration and this causes it to be namespaced, but the generated html is not and the styles dont apply. 

Unnamespaced HTML seems wrong... the question here is : how to deal with html generated by external libraries in an angular component context ?